# How to make varibles from array keys

Tags: php, arrays, function, scope, global-variables

I am trying to extract the keys of an array as variables. I have following code for that:

```
01 |    $array = [
02 |        "bantya" => "BANTYA",
03 |        "sontya" => "SONTYA",
04 |        "niltya" => "NILTYA"
05 |    ];
06 |
07 |    function makeVar ($array) {
08 |        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
09 |            $$key = $value;
10 |        }
11 |        echo $bantya;
12 |    }
13 |
14 |    makeVar($array);
15 |    echo $bantya;
```

The problem is, line 11 echoes "BANTYA" correctly, but the same about line 15 is not true. It says :

`Notice: Undefined variable: bantya in file\path on line 15`

My question is, why is it showing this error? How can I make line 15 to output "BANTYA" (which is outside of the scope of `function makeVar($array)`) globally after `makeVar` function is declared?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Woops. Use `extract()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: This seems useless. You still can get `BANTYA` by `echo $array['bantya']`

Comment: Assign to `$GLOBALS[$key]` instead of `$$key` to make a global variable. Or just use `extract()`.

Comment: Yes, using extract solved the case. 
and `echo $array['bantya']` was a solution but it is longer to type.

Comment: Lol, longer to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's will be helpful. Use `extract()` in PHP. See example below

`$array = (
         "bantya" => "BANTYA",
         "sontya" => "SONTYA",
         "niltya" => "NILTYA" 
  );
  extract($array);
  var_dump($bantya);`

And you obtain new var: `$bantya`, `$sontya`, `$niltya`